# how to Upgrade grails 1.3.7 project into grails 2.2.1 using GGTS 3.2.0

Tags: grails, upgrade

I have imported the grails 1.3.7 project into grails 2.2.1 using ggts 3.2.0. I have changed grails version,hibernate 
and tomcat version with 2.2.1 in application.properties file. But i am getting the following Error

```
Error loading plugin manager: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/convert/support/PropertyTypeDescriptor
```

Because GGTS's Grails dependencies spring core 3.1.1 have not `PropertyTypeDescriptor`. What is a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Run `grails dependency-report` to see if there is any clashing dependency for spring core.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Grails dependency giving spring core 3.1.4. It have not PropertyTypeDescriptor.So i replaced with my jar Spring core 3.0.6 that have the class.Now the problem got solved.